# Multiple Bootstrap Modals with Forms not Responding

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, paypal, bootstrap-modal

I'm using three bootstrap modals with identical html forms in each, with the exception of the PayPal button ID.

For some reason, on the live site I cannot type in the forms in modal 1 or 2 unless I've clicked on modal 3 and clicked in one of the text boxes. But the buttons at the end of each form work fine with or without the textboxes working. 
(& It's the same for Chrome, Mozilla and IE.)

Any suggestions?

Located at:
http://mytravelagentportal.com/deluxe/test/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap does not support multiple modals, so I wrote some javascript to switch out the button value for paypal and used one modal. Code can be seen at the same link.
This alternative was cleaner than using the three different modals anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because modal 2 doesn't have style="display: none;", it's just have opacity: 0, and you can't click on elements behind it (modal 1). And because of this you can't click on button 2, it's also behind hidden modal 2